# Move-Item with -match and -LiteralPath not working

Tags: powershell, move

I have a file move script that looks for files with keywords in the name and moves them to a specific folder. There's about a hundred lines that all work fine, except for one of them, and the only thing I can think of is that the file has brackets in the name.

I'm already using `-LiteralPath` to grab the full path, but the error is weird. I've tried double quotes, double backticks, and some other options that I've found elsewhere on the boards, but nothing is working.

Here is all the relevant parts of the script (without posting the whole thing):

```cs
# Source folders
$RecipesFolder = "F:\Downloads\Downloaded Recipes\"

# Destination Folders Drive I
$CoffeeRecipes = "I:\My Recipes\Coffee Recipes\"

# Get list of files
$Files = Get-ChildItem $RecipesFolder -File -Recurse

# Process Files
foreach ($File in $Files) {
    if ($File -match "Coffee") {
        Move-Item -LiteralPath $RecipesFolder$File -Destination "$CoffeeRecipes" -Force
    }
```

It's a really simple script, and every other line works fine, except that one. All the lines are written identically.

This is the full error I get (sourcepath obfuscated for security), and thank you in advance for any assistance:

```
Move-Item : Cannot move item because the item at 'F:\Downloads\Downloaded Recipes\[1] 
Coffee Recipe - 11[1].txt' does not exist.
At Path-to-powershell-script-file:153 char:13
+             Move-Item -LiteralPath $RecipesFolder$File -Destina ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Move-Item], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand
```

When I receive this error, the file disappears, and doesn't get moved to the folder, it just vanishes.

Comment: No need for LiteralPath here at all because `$file` is not a plain string but already references an actual file so simply `move $File $CoffeeRecipes`

Comment: Better yet, make proper use of the pipeline: `$Files | Where-Object { $_.Name -match 'coffee' } | Move-Item -Destination ...`

Comment: @wOxxOm Early on I needed to use the -LiteralPath switch to get something to work but I can't remember what now, but I took it out for this one I'm having issues with, ran the script again, and now I get no error, the file disappears from the source directory, but never makes it to the destination, it just vanishes.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers So use statements like that instead of all of the if statements?

Comment: For your scenario it's the more elegant approach.

Comment: I ran my script and changed the line I'm having issues with to:

$Files | Where-Object { $_.Name -match 'Coffee' } | Move-Item -Destination "$CoffeeRecipes" -Force

And I got a slightly different error, the still the source file vanishes and never makes it to the destination.

Comment: Move-Item : Cannot move item because the item at 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::SOURCE-FILE-PATH&FILE' does not exist.
At PATH-TO-POWERSHELL-SCRIPT:152 char:65
+ ...  -match 'Coffee' } | Move-Item -Destination "$CoffeeRecipes" -Force
+                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Move-Item], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers You know what, I was changing my script to use your line instead of all if statements, and I came across the issues. Earlier on in the script I had another move command for another "Coffee" named file, so it would move the file to the wrong directory, and by the time it hit the file that was supposed to go to "$CoffeeRecipes" the file didn't exist anymore.

Everything works now, thank you both!

Now how do I mark this as answered?

Comment: You could post an answer of your own and accept that, but frankly, I don't consider this question and answer too useful to anybody else, because the question doesn't contain a [mcve], so the original problem can't be reproduced in the first place.

Comment: Yeah you could. You could create 2 if statements, with the same match word, point it to the directory where that file with that match word is, run the script. The first if statement would move the file, and the second if statement would look for the file to move and give the above error because the file didn't exist anymore. Basically exactly what was going on in my case.